# Why don't (inherited) class constructors run?

Tags: delphi, class-constructors

I have the following code:

```
program ClassConstructor;

{$apptype console}

type
  TTree<K,V> = class(TObject)
  protected type
    TNode = class(TObject)
    end;
    TNodeType = class of TNode;
  protected
    class var NodeType: TNodeType;
  end;

  TThreadedTree<K,V> = class(TTree<K,V>)
  protected type
    TThreadedNode = class(TTree<K,V>.Tnode)
    end;
  protected
    class constructor Init;
  end;

  TRBThreadedTree<K,V> = class(TThreadedTree<K,V>)
  private
    class constructor Init;
  end;

  class constructor TThreadedTree<K,V>.Init;
  begin
    NodeType:= TThreadedNode;
    WriteLn('Class constructor for the plain threaded tree has run');
  end;

  class constructor TRBThreadedTree<K,V>.Init;
  begin
    NodeType:= TThreadedNode;
    WriteLn('Class constructor for the RedBlack threaded tree has run');
  end;


var
  Test: TThreadedTree<integer, integer>;
  RBTest: TRBThreadedTree<integer, integer>;

begin
  Test:= TThreadedTree<integer, integer>.Create;
  RBTest:= TRBThreadedTree<integer, integer>.Create;
  WriteLn('I see nothing');
  Readln;
end.
```

The idea is that I have a plain tree ancestor type with `Parented` and `Threaded` descendants, which than have RB, BST and AVL subtypes.
In order to abstract the threads/parent nodes as much as possible I wish to initialize the `NodeType` in a class constructor so that I can call.

```
NewNode:= NodeType.Create(Key, Value, Parent);
```

Instead of having to figure out if it's a parented or a threaded node.

**Question**
Why are the class constructor never called?
Not the inherited class constructor and not even the class constructor of the type itself.

I know I can do this initialization in the constructor, but it just irks me that the class constructor does not run.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

BTW I'm using Delphi 10, but XE7 shows the same behaviour.

Comment: I think I understand now why this problem occurs.  The class constructor acts as part of the `initialization` section in a unit file. However a `dpr` does not have an `initialization` section and hence the compiler does not place the code there. BTW this there a bug report for this (long-standing bug in the new bug portal?) Would be nice to have this fixed.

Comment: No, that's not it, because for a non-generic example it **does** run.

Comment: It would be nice to have it fixed, but it probably isn't a big problem in real world scenarios.